# Opening file in python using open() using "/" or r'filepath' gives error

Tags: python, file

All I'm trying to is open a file to read

```
file1 = open (r"C:\Users\Javier\Downloads\BodyFat.txt", "r" )
```

I get the error message:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '                                            
\u202aC:\\Users\\Javier\\Downloads\\BodyFat.txt'
```

If I proceed to manually change:

```
file1 = open ("C:/Users/Javier/Downloads/BodyFat.txt", "r" )
```

I get the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: ' 
\u202aC:/Users/Javier/Downloads/BodyFat.txt'
```

Edit 1: " C... " to "C..."

Edit 2:  Fixed problem with @spectras input about the invalid character, thank you

Edit 2.1: for some reason (below) works

```
 "/Users/Javier/Downloads/BodyFat.txt", "r"
```

Comment: Please use code blocks for your code and errors to improve readability.

Comment: You have an invalid character at the beginning of your path. Be careful when copy-pasting paths…

Comment: That's not what you're putting in it seems: You've got `'\xcaa'` (`ÃŠa`) going before the string, which aren't characters that you necessarily want in

Comment: you appear to have spaces in the code you have us at the beginning of the paths

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm "left to right embedding" are you on a computer with right to left defaults or something?

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
file1 = open ("C:/Users/Javier/Downloads/BodyFat.txt", "r" )
```

with

```
file1 = open ("/Users/Javier/Downloads/BodyFat.txt", "r" )
```

Python is looking for a directory, and `C:` is not being recognized as one.

Comment: Assuming he's on Windows, that's a perfectly valid file path.

Comment: I suspect when the `C:` was removed, the mysterious leading unicode character was also removed.  But, as they say, a win is a win!